# Let $E$ be measurable and define $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{x\in E : f(x)>c\}$ is measurable for all $c\in\mathbb{Q}$, is $f$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be measurable and define $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{x\in E : f(x)>c\}$ is measurable for all $c\in\mathbb{Q}$, is $f$ measurable?

There are a number of equivalent definitions for the measurability of a function and the most obvious one would be to show that $\{x\in E : f(x)>c\}$ is measurable for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thus my strategy has been to consider an arbitrary irrational $y$ and use the density of the rationals in the reals to show that there exists some open set $O$ such that $m^*(O-\{x\in E : f(x)>y\})< \varepsilon$.  I would do this by choosing some rational $q<y$, close enough to $y$, such that the set of values in $E$ which get sent under $f$ to values strictly greater than $q$ and less than or equal to $y$ is small enough.  But that doesn't in general seem possible since I could keep sending intervals of some fixed positive length to smaller and smaller regions just beneath $y$.  However conversely, such a function would not be enough for a counter example, since finding such a function only rules out this strategy, but doesn't necessarily entail non-measurability.

Is there a better definition of the measurability of a set I should use? or does the statement actually not imply measurability?  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing that $f$ is measurable.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140031/showing-that-f-is-measurable)

Comment: This is strange - I have seen this question in the queue for [reviewing close votes](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close), but when I come here, it seems that my vote is first...?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: The two aren't duplicates. The other specifies that that the $r$ are **irrational**, while this specifies that they're rational.

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry for my mistake, I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Given any $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, we can obtain $\{x\in E:f(x)>\alpha\}$ as the union of countably infinitely many sets of the form $\{x\in E:f(x)>c\}$ with $c\in\Bbb Q$. In particular, enumerate the rationals greater than $\alpha$ by $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, and show that $$\{x\in E:f(x)>\alpha\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{x\in E:f(x)>q_n\},$$ then use the fact that countable unions of measurable sets are measurable.

Comment: oh man so simple! Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron Buie Here is it  not necessary to choose $q_{n}$ such that $q_{n} \to \alpha$ ?

Comment: @ManojKumar That's certainly one approach you can take. Given any enumeration $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of $\{q\in\mathbb Q:q>\alpha\},$ one can prove that there is a subsequence $\left\{q_{n_j}\right\}_{j=1}^\infty$ that converges (monotonically) to $\alpha,$ and that $$\{x\in E:f(x)>\alpha\}=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty\left\{x\in E:f(x)>q_{n_j}\right\}.$$ It isn't necessary, though. The existence of such a subsequence follows from the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R,$ which is enough to prove $$\{x\in E:f(x)>\alpha\}\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{x\in E:f(x)>q_n\}.$$ The reverse inclusion is trivial.

Comment: @CameronBuie, is it enough to simply switch in the inequalities in the proof, if instead of the above, you are asked Let $ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{x\in \mathbb{R} :f(x)<c\}$ is measurable for all $c\in\mathbb{Q}$, is $f$ measurable?

Comment: @Isaac It depends in part on what definitions of "measurable" you have to work with. Assuming that one is "$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a measurable function if for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R,$ $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid f(x)<\alpha\}$ is measurable set," then it is as simple as reversing the inequalities. If you had only, say, the definition "$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a measurable function if for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R,$ $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid f(x)>\alpha\}$ is measurable set," then you'd need to proceed differently, perhaps by first taking the complements of the sets $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid f(x)<c\}$ for each $c\in Bbb Q.$

Comment: @CameronBuie I actually have both... Or rather a statement of equivalence. 
So I will just do the reversing. Thanks! :-)