# $f$ is measurable if and only if $A$ belongs to $X$ for all $\alpha \in \Bbb Q$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A function f on $X$ to $\Bbb R$ is said to be X-measurable (or simply measurable) if for all $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, the set $A_\alpha=$ {$x\in X: f(x)\gt \alpha$} belongs to $X$.

I need to prove that the function $f$ is measurable **if and only if** the set $A\_\alpha$ belongs to $X$ for all rational number $\alpha \in \Bbb Q$.

My thought is that the direction that "if $f$ is measurable then $A_\alpha$ is measurable for all $\alpha \in \Bbb Q$" is straightforward because each rational number is a real number; For the direction that "if the set $A_\alpha$ is measurable for all rational number $\alpha \in \Bbb Q$, then $f$ is measurable", it can be solved from the post [Let $E$ be measurable and define $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{x\in E : f(x)>c\}$ is measurable for all $c\in\mathbb{Q}$, is $f$ measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228605/let-e-be-measurable-and-define-fe-rightarrow-mathbbr-such-that-x-in-e?lq=1)

Are my thoughts correct so far? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about $A$ belongs to $X$? $A$ is by definition a subset of $X$?

Comment: Your logic seems fine. As @user251257 indicated, you seem to be overloading $X$ to mean both the domain of the function $f$ and the $\sigma$ algebra of measurable subsets of $X$.

Comment: Thanks, it might be better if I just state $f$ is measurable instead of "A belongs to X for all $\alpha \in \Bbb Q$"